# how user Rails routes on js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes

I need got a path on my JavaScript and Ruby file. I need a route for an ajax, in it I can't get the rails routes.

How do I made `"<%= route_path %>"` works?

Comment: What do you mean, "route for ajax"?

Answer (score 3):

You can put <%= route_path %> on data attribute in your view, then on js you can take it.
For example, view:

```
<div id="test-div" data-url="<%= route_path %>"> 
 ....
</div>
```

on js:

```
var url = $('#test-div').data('url');
```